Can we see quantifier elimination by comparing semirings?
This question came up while reading the paper Hales, What is motivic measure?. Broadly speaking, I'm interested in which ideas from motivic measure make sense in arbitrary first-order theories (or even more general classes of structures).

Given a first-order theory $T$, let $\widehat{D}(T)$ be the semiring defined as follows:

Elements of $\widehat{D}(T)$ are equivalence classes of formal $\mathbb{N}$-linear combinations of first-order formulas in the language of $T$.

The equivalence relation $\sim$ is the finest one satisfying the following properties (writing "$[\varphi]$" for the $\sim$-class of $\varphi$):

$[\varphi\vee\psi]+[\varphi\wedge\psi]=[\varphi]+[\psi]$. (I messed this up in the initial version of this question, but that doesn't affect the answer below.)

If $\varphi,\psi$ share no variables in common then $[\varphi]\cdot [\psi]=[\varphi\wedge\psi]$.

$[\varphi]=n[\psi]$ whenever there is a formula $\theta$ which $T$ proves defines a $n$-to-one surjection from the set of tuples satisfying $\varphi$ to the set of tuples satisfying $\psi$.




(If I have things right this is one step away from the Grothendieck ring; maybe this is the "Grothendieck semiring" of $T$?) "He did not in fact have things right."
Now syntactic classes generate subsemirings of $\widehat{D}(T)$, and so certain logical properties have "algebraic" analogues. The simplest natural one seems to be the following: say that $T$ has algebraic quantifier elimination iff every element of $\widehat{D}(T)$ has a representative in the subring generated by quantifier-free formulas. Obviously quantifier-elimination in the usual sense implies its algebraic analogue.

Does the converse hold?

Note that we can have $[\varphi]=[\psi]$ even if no definable bijection between the corresponding sets of tuples exists. (E.g. consider the theory of a five-element structure with domain $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and two unary relations $U,V$ picking out $\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}$ respectively; then $[U(x)]=2[\neg (U(x)\vee V(x))]=[V(x)]$ but no definable bijection between $U$ and $V$ exists.)
Although this question isn't directly about algebraic geometry, I've used that tag since I think there's a good chance that an easy counterexample comes from that subject; that said, feel free to remove that tag.

Note that we for $T$ the theory of an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ your construction doesn't produce, after adding additive inverses, the Grothendieck ring of varieties: The final relation arising from an $n$-to-one surjection only holds in the Grothendieck ring if $n=1$. So this might not be the right relation to use for an arbitrary logical theory.

@WillSawin Oh oops, I think I got things a bit mixed up then. I'm still interested in this definition, though I'll update to address your point.

No, for example consider $T=\mathsf{Th}(\mathbb{N};=,0,1,+)$, i.e. Presburger arithmetic in non-extended signature.
Quantifier elimination does not hold for this $T$: this would require to extend the signature by the formulas $x<y$ and $x\equiv y \pmod p$, for prime $p$. In particular this predicates are definable in the language of $T$ by first-order formulas, but not by quantifier-free formulas.
However, it is easy to prove (using the quantifier elimination in the extended signature) that any $(\mathbb{N};=,0,1,+)$-definable subset of $\mathbb{N}^n$ is $(\mathbb{N};=,0,1,+)$-definably equinumerous to either $[0,k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ or to $\mathbb{N}^k$, for some $k\le n$. In other words, your semiring of internal cardinalities will consist of finite naturals (cardinalities of finite sets) and $\omega^k$, for finite $k$. Every element here clearly is represented by some quantifier-free formula. And thus the theory possesses "algebraic quantifier elimination".

Thanks, this is great! FYI I got the definition slightly wrong (see edit) but that doesn't affect this answer.
